# The well-posedness of $-(p u')' + q u=f$ on $(0, 1)$ with boundary conditions $u'(0)= u'(1)=0$

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, sturm-liouville

Let $I$ be the open interval $(0, 1)$. Assume that $p \in C^1(\bar I)$ and $q \in$ $C(\bar I)$ such that $p(x) \geq \alpha>0$ and $q(x) \geq \alpha>0$ for all $x \in \bar I$. Here $\alpha$ is a constant. Let $f \in L^2 (I)$. I would like to verify a claim in Brezis' *exercise 8.26* that the system
$$
(1) \quad 
\begin{cases}
-(p u')' + q u=f \quad \text{on} \quad I,\\
u'(0)= u'(1)=0,
\end{cases}
$$
has a unique (weak) solution in $H^2 (I)$.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in my below attempt. Could you please have a check on it?

---

If $u$ is a classical solution to $(1)$, then
$$
(2) \quad 
\int_I [-(p u')'w + q uw] = \int_I fw,
\quad \forall w \in H^1 (I),
$$
which (by integration by parts) implies
$$
(3) \quad 
\int_I [p u'w' + q uw] = \int_I fw,
\quad \forall w \in H^1 (I).
$$

We define a continuous symmetric bilinear form $a$ on $H^1 (I)$ by
$$
a(u, w) :=  \int_I [p u'w' + q uw].
$$

We have
$$
a(u, u) = \int_I [p |u'| + q |u|^2] \ge \alpha \|u\|^2_{H^1},
$$
which implies $a$ is coercive. By Lax-Milgram theorem, $(3)$ has a unique solution $u \in H^1 (I)$. From $(3)$, we also have
$$
\int_I (p u')w' = -\int_I (qu-f)w,
\quad \forall w \in H^1 (I),
$$
which implies $(p u')'=qu-f$ and thus $pu' \in H^1 (I)$. Because $p \ge \alpha >0$ and $p' \in C (\bar I)$, we get $\frac{1}{p} \in H^1 (I)$.

> **Corollary 8.10** Let $I$ be a (possibly unbounded) open interval of $\mathbb R$. Let $u, v \in W^{1, p}(I)$ with $1 \leq p \leq$ $\infty$. Then $u v \in W^{1, p}(I)$ and  $(u v)^{\prime}=u^{\prime} v+u v^{\prime}$. Furthermore, the formula for integration by parts holds:
> $$
> \int_y^x u^{\prime} v=u(x) v(x)-u(y) v(y)-\int_y^x u v^{\prime} \quad \forall x, y \in \bar{I} .
> $$

By above corollary (in the same book), we get $u' \in H^1 (I)$ and thus $u \in H^2 (I)$. It follows from $(3)$ and $(p u')'=qu-f$ and integration by parts that
$$
(pu'w)(1)-(pu'w)(0)=0,
\quad \forall w \in H^1 (I),
$$
which implies
$$
(pu')(1) = (pu')(0)=0,
$$
which implies
$$
u'(1) = u'(0)=0.
$$

Comment: What about the case where there is a non-trivial solution of $-(pv')'+qv=0$ that satisfies $v'(0)=0, v'(1)=0$. Then $u+v$ and $u$ are solutions of your problem. Aren't they?